# How to adapt Wordpress WP Tiles Plugin / Pixellab's tiles.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm really stuck on this one!

I'm using the WP Tiles plugin (http://wp-tiles.com/) to display custom post types for a new Wordpress project. Everything works fine EXCEPT that the tiles are displayed as squares. HOWEVER, my graphic designer wants the tiles to display as rectangles (see this for an example: http://greensenseweb.info/wptilesproblem.jpg).

There's been no reply from the plugin developer, so I guess I'm on my own on this one. I've already delved into the plugin and have seen it uses Pixellab's tiles.js (http://thinkpixellab.com/tilesjs/).

Unfortunately, my javascript is average at the best of times! How can I adjust the plugin or tiles.js to give me rectangles instead of squares?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same problem.
I've been trying to use a jQuery workaround like this:

```
jQuery('.wp-tiles-tile').height((jQuery('.wp-tiles-tile').width())*0.8);
```

but obviously it only works for a static page, as soon as you resize the window its not working anymore (plus its not really a clean solution).